# How to return result from JSON_OBJECT with lowecase column names in Oracle 19C

Tags: json, oracle

In Oracle 19C I created the table:

```sql
create table SAMPLE_TABLE (    
  id            NUMBER not null,  
  display_name  NVARCHAR2(200), )
```

When I run the query:

```
select JSON_OBJECT(s.*) from SAMPLE_TABLE s
```

I am getting the following result. All column names are presented with capital letters.

```
{"ID":1,"DISPLAY_NAME":"Test_1"}
```

Is there any setting or query option to return the column names with lowercase e.g.

```
{"id":1,"display_name":"Test_1"}
```

Comment: [`select json_object(s.*) from sample_table s;`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f363029061b875fd2e4ea982c3505f57) already shouldn't work( I tested by 18c ). Is it really working on 19c..?

Comment: This functionality was added in 19c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can give any name to the generated `JSON` object attributes. You need to use name and value for the attribute as following:

```
SQL>
SQL> SELECT
  2      JSON_OBJECT ( 'account nr' VALUE A.ACC_NR, 'Customer Id' VALUE A.CUST_ID ) as json_val
  3  FROM
  4      ACCOUNT A;

JSON_VAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"account nr":500,"Customer Id":100}

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. However, is there any way to influence the column names returned from JSON_OBJECT (*) ?